# Can I query the Email customer key or retrieve via AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

I need to get the Email (Content Builder) Customer Key, this isn't available in the email send context as a personalisation string and the the `_job` table only gives back the Asset ID.

Any other way I can get this out?

(Ideally without having to use the API, as this will be run in an automation in batch, I think the overhead will increase the execution time too much).

Comment: Unless there's an undocumented field or data view table, then you're only going to get that through the API

Comment: You can get `emailname_` though if you need a more descriptive identifier.

Comment: You're right I didn't think of this, but I don't think email names are uniquely enforced so I could have multiple results.